# MSYS2 Qt-creator examples not showing

Tags: qt, mingw-w64, msys2

I have installed qt-creator on windows 10 using msys2.

I installed packages according to https://wiki.qt.io/MSYS2

- base-devel git mercurial cvs wget p7zip
- perl ruby python2 mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
- mingw-w64-i686-qt-creator mingw-w64-x86_64-qt-creator

I had previously installed qt from the official site but the mingw version is too old and I'd rather not have two mingw versions installed.

I have existing C:\msys64\mingw64\share\qt5\examples folder but it seems there are some folders missing from C:\msys64\mingw64\share\qt5\doc compared to the official install. Maybe that has something to do with it.

So the question: Is there a specific package I need to install so that the examples show up in the qt-creator examples page or something else?

Comment: I think it'd be easier to install Qt from the official site, and use MSYS2 only for the compiler.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Build Qt apps within a MSYS2 (POSIX) environment?  Or just use the MinGW compiler to build Win32 applications?  Qt for Windows doesn't use MSYS2 (it uses MinGW-w64 **compiler**).  The MinGW version distributed with Qt installers is not "too old," it's the right version for that Qt distribution. But you can also simply delete it and change the Qt kits in QtCreator to use whatever compiler version you have (or just create symlinks from where Qt installed MinGW to your own installation).

Comment: I'm using msys2 just to install mingw-w64 basically. I build 64-bit applications which aren't hopefully tied to Windows. When you do the official install and choose the qt-creator version and then it forcefully installs whatever compiler is associated with that version. So with every update I end up in a loop of always deleting the "wrong" mingw version. I meant the mingw version was "too old" for my purposes not that it is the wrong version for the program necessarily.

Comment: Installing MSYS just to get the w64 compiler doesn't make sense if you're trying to save space on your system. Why not just install the compiler on its own? Also you should not run the MSYS version of QtCreator in Windows, that doesn't really make sense either (why do you possibly want to do that?). "I build 64-bit applications which aren't hopefully tied to Windows." Maybe I don't understand, but of course they'll still be Windows-only apps... in this case they'll be MSYS2-Windows-only apps. You cannot build cross-platform apps this way. Your purpose still not clear at all.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of confusion about what msys2 does. At least you've got me perplexed. 

Msys2 is an easy and convenient way to install and update mingw-compiler. It is also a superior way to update Qt compared to the official one. Also the Qt-creator version doesn't come with the old compiler.

Please explain how are they windows only apps? That doesn't make any sense. We use Qt exactly because it allows us to create applications that work on different platforms. 

What's this msys2-windows-only app? How does msys2 enter the picture?

Comment: Much of this is irrelevant to the actual question but maybe you can clear this up for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea where you're getting your information from, maybe we're somehow discussing entirely different things. MSYS2 is a POSIX runtime environment for Windows (it uses the w64 compiler to build Windows versions of GNU utilities). Eg. you want to use a bash shell. In no way is it a "superior way to update Qt" for Windows. Applications built in MSYS2 (or Cygwin or any other layer) are not going to run on, say, Linux or any other POSIX system. Generally you build Linux apps on LInux, Mac on Mac, etc (from the same Qt code). There's no "build once run anywhere." The code is portable.

Comment: How is going through the whole MSYS2 install procedure simpler than just downloading and installing https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/  ?

Comment: I think I posted a pretty simple question. Wether there is a solution is another thing. I don't know why ya'll want to blow this out of proportions. I don't really wish to create a debate here and hope you won't either. That is just a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 0):

The qt-creator in msys2 distribution do not have examples installed. The msys2 also do not have separate package for it.

But as what @user3930978 found. You can use example package from archlinux site for workaround.

But unfortunately, msys2 qt5 configured with "-nomake examples" parameter. You need  to modify generated file. The easiest way is still to install qt5 and creator with official full pack.

Answer (score 0):

I found in this place https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/qt5-examples/
decompress with
zstd -df qt5-examples-5.14.2-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
and then
tar xzf qt5-examples-5.14.2-1-any.pkg.tar
the examples are saved in /usr/share/doc/qt/examp,es